# user-defined ordering in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the field *status* as `enum(1,2,3,4,5)` and i need to `order 2,3 DESC` and then `1,4,5 DESC`. The resul must be `3,2,5,4,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary order by:

```
order by case [enum]
  when 3 then 1
  when 2 then 2
  when 5 then 3
  when 4 then 4
  when 1 then 5
end
```